# compare objects of same array and group their some properties when specific property matched with other object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of object as following :

```
    "orders": [
        {
            "orderID": 1,
            "fullName": "xyz",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "phone": "12345",
            "flatNo": "A-5",
            "complex": "tara tra",
            "landmark": null,
            "street": null,
            "area": "",
            "city": "",
            "productID": 2,
            "name": "curd",
            "price": 52,
            "image": "curd.png",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "orderID": 1,
            "fullName": "xyz",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "phone": "12345",
            "flatNo": "A-5",
            "complex": "tara tra",
            "landmark": null,
            "street": null,
            "area": "",
            "city": "",
            "productID": 1,
            "name": "lassi",
            "price": 65,
            "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "orderID": 2,
            "fullName": "velocity",
            "email": "velocity@gmail.com",
            "phone": "999999",
            "flatNo": "b-863",
            "complex": "tara tra",
            "landmark": "kaskd",
            "street": "asdasd",
            "area": "rob city",
            "city": "asda",
            "productID": 1,
            "name": "lassi",
            "price": 65,
            "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG",
            "quantity": 3
        }
    ]
```

Here if the orderID is same for the object I want to merge those object into a single object and create the product information into an array of an object within the main array

Here is the output which I am looking for

```
        "orders": [
            {
                "orderID": 1,
                "fullName": "xyz",
                "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
                "phone": "12345",
                "flatNo": "A-5",
                "complex": "tara tra",
                "landmark": null,
                "street": null,
                "area": "",
                "city": "",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "productID": 2,
                        "name": "curd",
                        "price": 52,
                        "image": "curd.png",
                        "quantity": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "productID": 1,
                        "name": "lassi",
                        "price": 65,
                        "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                "orderID": 2,
                "fullName": "velocity",
                "email": "velocity@gmail.com",
                "phone": "999999",
                "flatNo": "b-863",
                "complex": "tara tra",
                "landmark": "kaskd",
                "street": "asdasd",
                "area": "rob city",
                "city": "asda",
                "productID": 1,
                "name": "lassi",
                "price": 65,
                "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG",
                "quantity": 3
            }
        ]
```

basically I want to combine product information if the order ID is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if you want to do it through plain `JavaScript` you can make use of `reduce`:

```js
var data=[ { "orderID": 1, "fullName": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "phone": "12345", "flatNo": "A-5", "complex": "tara tra", "landmark": null, "street": null, "area": "", "city": "", "productID": 2, "name": "curd", "price": 52, "image": "curd.png", "quantity": 1 }, { "orderID": 1, "fullName": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "phone": "12345", "flatNo": "A-5", "complex": "tara tra", "landmark": null, "street": null, "area": "", "city": "", "productID": 1, "name": "lassi", "price": 65, "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG", "quantity": 1 }, { "orderID": 2, "fullName": "velocity", "email": "velocity@gmail.com", "phone": "999999", "flatNo": "b-863", "complex": "tara tra", "landmark": "kaskd", "street": "asdasd", "area": "rob city", "city": "asda", "productID": 1, "name": "lassi", "price": 65, "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG", "quantity": 3 } ];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {productID, name, price,image, quantity, ...rest})=>{
   acc[rest.orderID] = acc[rest.orderID] || {...rest, products:[]};
   acc[rest.orderID].products.push({productID, name, price,image, quantity});
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have an easy time if you use my library for this.

```js
const data = { orders: [  { "orderID": 1, "fullName": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "phone": "12345", "flatNo": "A-5", "complex": "tara tra", "landmark": null, "street": null, "area": "", "city": "", "productID": 2, "name": "curd", "price": 52, "image": "curd.png", "quantity": 1 }, { "orderID": 1, "fullName": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "phone": "12345", "flatNo": "A-5", "complex": "tara tra", "landmark": null, "street": null, "area": "", "city": "", "productID": 1, "name": "lassi", "price": 65, "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG", "quantity": 1 }, { "orderID": 2, "fullName": "velocity", "email": "velocity@gmail.com", "phone": "999999", "flatNo": "b-863", "complex": "tara tra", "landmark": "kaskd", "street": "asdasd", "area": "rob city", "city": "asda", "productID": 1, "name": "lassi", "price": 65, "image": "images\\rtoRAOwj4-conn.PNG", "quantity": 3 } ] }

const { pipe, assign, reduce, get, pick, omit } = rubico

const productKeys = ['productID', 'name', 'price', 'image', 'quantity']

const addOrderToMap = (m, order) => {
  if (m.has(order.orderID)) {
    m.get(order.orderID).products.push(pick(productKeys)(order))
  } else {
    m.set(order.orderID, {
      ...omit(productKeys)(order),
      products: [pick(productKeys)(order)],
    })
  }
  return m
}

const groupedByOrderID = assign({
  orders: pipe([ // assign orders key
    get('orders'), // data => orders
    reduce(addOrderToMap, new Map()), // orders => Map { orderID -> orderWithProducts }
    m => m.values(), // Map { orderID -> orderWithProducts } -> iterator { orderWithProducts }
    Array.from, // iterator { orderWithProducts } -> [orderWithProducts]
  ]),
})(data)

console.log(groupedByOrderID)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico/index.js"></script>
```

I've commented the code for you, here's the [tour](https://tour.rubico.land/) if you'd like to learn more.

Comment: Also I'll be active here if you have any further questions.

Comment: Amazing stuff :)